# How to transfer the only updated file on FTP Server into client machine using VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

How to transfer the only updated file on FTP Server into client machine using VB.NET? I have to transfer the only updated file to client machine through FTP from server machine where changes occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [FileSystemWatcher Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) and FTP only the files that have changed. See the following [VB.NET example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2). Specifically, you should hook into the [OnChanged event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.onchanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

For example:

```
Private Shared Sub OnChanged(source As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)
 ' your FTP code here
End Sub
```